# Grep_color on mac

Tags: grep, osx, colors

I am trying to get my regex highlighted on mac using terminal. I have put this is my `.profile`:

```
export GREP_COLOR='1;30;40'
```

Nothing changes, so I added the same to my `bash.profile` still nothing, restarted the machine nothing. When I am:

```
egrep --color=auto ".*\W blah blah "
```

then it lights up some yellow color but I wondered if I had done something wrong in my `.profile` or `bash_profile`.

Any help would be good: snow leopard, with just plain old terminal :-)

Comment: Isn't `GREP_COLOR` deprecated?  Anyways `grep --color` should highlight matches in the default color, without any need for environment variables.

Comment: That's only half true. `GREP_COLOR` allows you to customize the actual colors, whereas `--color` only enables/disables whatever colors are configured by default. And I THINK `GREP_COLORS` (plural) is what is deprecated. That's why my coloring form years ago disappeared without me noticing.

Comment: @SridharSarnobat Nope. Quite the opposite. The singular version `GREP_COLOR` is the deprecated option. The plural version is recommended.

Answer (score 26):

This worked on my snow leopard machine. Try just copying and pasting the text in your terminal and seeing if grep shows the desired behavior. If it does, then the problem is you're not adding it to the right dotfile. What shell are you using? The dotfile you should add it to depends on the shell you use.

```
export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=auto'
export GREP_COLOR='1;30;40'
```

Also, try running `printenv` to see what environmental variables you already have set and see if any grep options are already.

Comment: excellent!!! thank you!! much better than setting up an alias!

Comment: Weird.  I was going to vote this answer up, but it didn't work for me using Terminal on Snow Leopard.  It turned the matched text into all-black boxes.

Comment: @OldPro - I would recommend actually using `export GREP_COLOR='1;35;40'` because 35 is cyan and 30 is gray- 40 is black background, so it looks dark. But yes it works! :)

Comment: My terminal has become a lot more beautiful. I know true beauty is on the inside but I'm superficial.

Comment: is it possible to apply same colors for `less` as well?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Snow Leopard's default setting is to use color for `grep`. I've had success on my OS X box with adding a line like `alias grep=grep --color=always` in my `.bashrc` to ensure consistent highlighting.

Comment: `--color=always` can be a problem if grep's output is piped to another command. `--color=auto` will emit the control characters for only when the output is directly displayed on the terminal

Answer (score 1):

It's not `bash.profile` nor `bash_profile`, it's `.bash_profile`.

As for the colors on your Mac, just put this in your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=auto'
export GREP_COLOR='1;30;40'
```

Be sure to use `.bash_profile` in your home directory (`~/`).